# How to scroll a UITableview opened through a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uipopovercontroller

In iOS 4, I have a UIPopoverController that opens a UITableViewController with a long list of items (66).
How do I programmatically scroll to a specific cell of the tableview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1] atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
```

Comment: Let me clarify you that its not a copied / duplicate answer. Just see the timing differences between all of the answers are very minor.

Comment: Well, I'm not here to argue on such a silly things. Anyways...leave it.

Comment: iApple, thank you for your answer. What was missing in my implementation was 'self.' (in self.tableView), and your answer helped me clarify this point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method of `UITableView`:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

**Parameters**

1. *indexPath*:
   An index path that identifies a row in the table view by its row index and its section index.
2. *scrollPosition*:
   A constant that identifies a relative position in the receiving table view (top, middle, bottom) for row when scrolling concludes. See “Table View Scroll Position” a descriptions of valid constants.
3. *animated*:
   YES if you want to animate the change in position, NO if it should be immediate.

Comment: Thank you Nekto for your answer, it was helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSIndexPath * someRowAtIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:4];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:someRowAtIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```